# my upVoteCount is not updated in the backend and it does not persist

Tags: flutter, api, setstate

//the iconbutton is given as
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
children: [
Text(
'views: ${widget.answerData.views}',
style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
),
Text('Answers: ${widget.answerData.answerCount}',
style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
Row(
children: [
IconButton(
onPressed: () async {
print(isLiked);
setState(() {

```
                                 isLiked=!isLiked;
                                 if (isLiked) {
                                   widget.answerData.voteCount += 1;
                                 } else {
                                   widget.answerData.voteCount -= 1;
                                 }

                                });
                                print(isLiked);

                                await updateVoteCount(widget.answerData.id);
                              },
                              icon: isLiked
                                  ? const Icon(
                                      Icons.thumb_up,
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                    )
                                  : const Icon(
                                      Icons.thumb_up_off_alt_outlined)),
//updateVoteCount function as
Future<void> updateVoteCount(int id) async {
    final answerToken = await storage.read(key: 'token');

    int id = widget.answerData.id;
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://queryus-production.up.railway.app/vote/question/$id'),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer $answerToken',
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) 
      print(widget.answerData.upVoted);
        widget.answerData.upVoted=!isLiked;
        print(widget.answerData.upVoted);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to update vote count');
    }
  }
```

I am expecting to fix my bugs that appeared during my personal project